# Is there a correct way to do iTunes Connect build numbers?

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, build-numbers

I did my build numbers as 1, and then 2.

Does this matter - is it just a mater of preference as to how you do them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Build Number (or `CFBundleVersion`) is not shown in the App Store so for the user it does not really matter.

The purpose of the Build Number is that developers can distinguish different builds using the same Version (`CFBundleShortVersionString`).

Consider you are working towards a version `2.1.0`. Before you publish this version on the App Store, you probably want to distribute Beta builds to testers. If they report any issues and you fix them, you will need to create and upload a new build but probably still use the version `2.1.0`. In that case you would use the Build Number to distinguish the two version.

You can use whatever you like as a build version. Apple provides a tool to increase the Build Number in Xcode projects named [`agvtool`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1827/_index.html). 
Another way (and what I personally do) is to use the git commit count as the Build Number. This can be [automated via a Build Phase](http://www.mokacoding.com/blog/automatic-xcode-versioning-with-git/). That way, every change that you make (and commit) automatically increases your Build Number.

Comment: What about when you use a new version - do you reset your build number for that version?

Comment: Personally I don't, as I use the git commit count and that will never be reset. If you use another method to generate your build numbers or set them manually, you can of course reset it if you want to.

Comment: Ok thanks, you have been very helpful, and thank you for taking your time to help me :).

Comment: naglerrr, I usually do and have seen several other iOS developers, resetting the build number when increasing the version number. But like @D-AUK answered you, it also depends on your build/deployment process.